# How to set hour/minute/second in NSDateComponents with a string?

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents, nsdatepicker

I am having a small problem with *NSDateComponents*.

What I have right now looks like this: [2014-8-08 08:00:00] because I'm using the current time initially (using [NSDate date]), and then setting the hours, minutes and seconds manually to something else through *comps*.

My objective is to separate the date from the time using a string. I still want to be able to use the current time, but when it comes to [comps set Hour/Minute/Second], I want to set them all using a string.

The string would be formatted like this: (06:00:00).

I need to set this as my default choice when opening NSDatePicker. So, it should look like [2014-8-08 06:00:00] initially when selecting a date.

**Is there any way that I can set the hour/minute/second through a string?**

**I HAVE to use a string. the 06:00:00 resembles a MYSQL query for when a store opens it's doors. I am working with hundreds of stores. Each store has different opening times.**
Thanks

Franco

```
startTimeDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
startTimeDatePicker.maximumDate = now;


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comps setHour:8];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *dateFromComps = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: Why are you using a string?  It's the wrong data type.

Comment: Sorry for the repost. @Droppy I have to use a string. Yogesh, your answer did not work for me. The reason I have to use a string is because the 06:00:00 comes directly from MYSQL query. It resembles when the store opens it's doors. And I am doing this for hundreds of stores so they all open their doors at different times.

Comment: So the question is about parsing a string with "06:00:00" into integers of hour/minute/second.  Nothing else.

Comment: Yes I need the NSDatePicker to by default, set the hours/minutes/seconds to the query (06:00:00). There is also another NSDatePicker with the end time (store closes doors). So when a customer picks a date, the first date picker should be defaulted as (store opens) and second as (store closes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct answer. You must separate the string individually, and input them into the components.

```
NSArray *results = [storeOpen componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
if ([results count] == 3) {
    NSLog(@"1 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"2 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:1] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"3 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:2] intValue]);


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comps setHour:[[results objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
[comps setMinute:[[results objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
[comps setSecond:[[results objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];


NSDate *dateFromComps = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```